# NetBeans - where to find the IDE log?

Tags: netbeans

I reported a bug to http://issues.apache.org I have to give them a IDE log, but I have no clue where to find it?

I searched in `C:\Users\MyUser` but there is no folder for netbeans.

I am on windows.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The logfile is stored in the "User Directory". 
The location of the user directory is shown under "Help -> About". 
Inside that directory the logfile itself can be found in the sub-directory `var\log` and is named `messages.log`

You can display the log file directly inside the IDE using "View -> IDE Log". The first view lines of the logfile also include the information about the user directory.

That is helpful if you just want to copy & paste a part of the logfile (e.g. the exception of the error you are reporting).

Comment: mhm, what if the error I'm looking for is about not being able to run it? ;)

Answer (score 7):

The NetBeans IDE keeps its log messages in a file called /var/log/messages.log in the NetBeans userdir.

Windows 7 : C:\Users\joe\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\7.2\var\log\messages.log

Windows XP : c:\Documents and Settings\joe\Application Data\NetBeans\7.3\var\log\messages.log
Application Data directory is localised to your Windows XP installation language

Source : http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqLogMessagesFile

Answer (score 1):

For macOS it is located here:

```
/Users/{username}/Library/Application\ Support/NetBeans/{version}/var/log/messages.log
```