# Netbeans 10 not installing

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm having issues trying to install NetBean 10 (incubating) on a laptop. I've checked that Java is installed, as well as JDK (jdk1.8.0_191). I've checked that Java is installed correctly by going to the command line and typing "java -version" and it correctly responds

java version "1.8.0_191"
Java(TM)SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_191-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.191-b12, mixed mode)

I've checked that the environment varible "JAVA_HOME" is correct (echo %JAVA_HOME%), and that the Path variable is correct.

However when I try installing NetBeans (from the C:\netbeans10\bin\netbeans64.exe) (yes, also double checked the laptop is correctly running Win10 64bit, it is) a logo for netbeans briefly appears, goes away after 1 sec, and nothing else happens.

I've tried downloading a fresh NetBeans, reinstalling Java, rebooting the system, disabled anti-virus, disabled firewall, tried from safe boot, however it just does not install.

Anyone have any ideas on what step I'm missing so that I can get this installed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Getting NetBeans up and running is a simple three step process: [1] Download the zip from the [NetBeans 10.0 web site](http://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb100/nb100.html). [2] Unzip it into some empty directory. [3] Start NetBeans by running **bin\netbeans64.exe** from within the directory you unzipped to. **There is no installer for NetBeans 10.0**, so your statement that _"I try **installing** NetBeans (from the C:\netbeans10\bin\netbeans64.exe)..."_ makes no sense. It sounds like you have unzipped the download, but when you try to run NetBeans it won't start - is that the situation?

Comment: Thanks, but that is correct. It is not running.

Answer (score 1):

A possible caused of your problem is that NetBeans is trying to run using a version of Java that does not exist on your machine. To eliminate this as a possibility:

- Locate the file **netbeans.conf**. It will be in the **etc** directory within the NetBeans installation directory.
- Open the file in any text editor. It is just a properties file containing name/value pairs,
- Locate the line containing the text **netbeans_jdkhome**.
- If the line is commented out delete the leading **#** character.
- Set the value to the actual path to your JDK. For example, on my machine it would be: `netbeans_jdkhome="C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_191"`.
- Save the file and (re)start NetBeans. NetBeans will now use the JDK specified by the `netbeans_jdkhome` property.
- If NetBeans still doesn't start then update your question with the content of the NetBeans log. See [NetBeans - where to find the IDE log?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50462124/2985643) for details on locating that file.

One other point: although you can run NetBeans 10.0 using JDK 8, I can't think of any good reason to do that. Most users will probably download and install JDK 11, and use that instead.

Comment: Fixed, from your suggestion, many thanks.

There was no log file, messages.log was nowhere on the drive. However I did download JDK 11, updated the config file, update environment variables, rebooted, retried, and it works. Why it works I don't know, and ditto on why it was not loading with JDK 8. However the answer to this is trivial.

Thanks again. Kudos.

Comment: @James Cool. I suspect (part of) the problem may have been due to reinstalling Java after NetBeans was installed. Now that you have things working it's worth locating and opening the NetBeans log file just in case you need to refer to it in future. You can open it within NetBeans using **View > IDE Log**.

Comment: @James I am having the same issues and the approach above has not worked for me ... are there any other fixes you could recommend?

Comment: @skomisa I tried all options you provided james and they did not work for me. When I click on the netbeans.exe file nothing happens (it does not launch) but when I click on it a second time it does launch, but it launches as a tiny window that I have to expand. When I expand it, the only things I get/see is the topmost navigation pane (with the file, edit, view .... options). Apart from that, the rest of the IDE blank, pluggins are blank as well ... any thoughts figuring this out?

Comment: @nigus21 OK... [1] What version(s) of Java do you have installed on your machine? [2] What does file **netbeans.conf** show for the property **netbeans_jdkhome**? See my answer above for more details on obtaining that information.

Comment: @skomisa I have the jdk-11.0.2 installed and I did change the netbeans_jdkhome="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11-11.0.1" in the netbeans.conf file, based on the answer you provided ... did not fix it. I uninstalled Java and removed Netbeans 10, reinstalled java (using jdk 8 then jdk 11) then netbeans 10 twice and it did not solve the problem either so I am not sure how to approach the issue ... any ideas? Also, when I click on View to access IDE log, IDE log does not open ...

Comment: OK...[1] You probably need to raise this as a new SO question. [2] It sounds like you are doing everything correctly overall, but try running **netbeans64.exe** instead of **netbeans.exe**. [3] Are you certain that the folder name **jdk-11-11.0.1** is correct? It doesn't look right. Should it perhaps be **jdk-11.0.1** instead? It's vital that the value of **netbeans_jdkhome** specifies the correct path to your Java installation, and if it doesn't NetBeans may show the symptoms you are seeing.

Comment: @skomisa apologies for the typo. I actually used "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2" to specify the file path to my java jdk 11 directory. I also tried setting up with netbeans64.exe since I have a 64bit system. Came up short! Btw, should I also uncomment (i.e. remove the # that comes before) the line that specifies the jdk in the netbeans.conf file? (I did that ... or should I leave it commented instead?)

Comment: @nigus21 Well it sounds like you are doing everything correctly, and the line in **netbeans.conf** should not contain a leading **#**. In your case it should be: `netbeans_jdkhome="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2"`. Also, verify that this works from the _Command Prompt_: `"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2\bin\java" -version`. If it does then create a new SO question which shows the content of **netbeans.conf** and the content of the _Command Prompt_ window as text (i.e. not as a screen shot).