# NetBeans IDE 8.2 not opening properly

Tags: java, netbeans-8

I downloaded NETBEANS 8.2 with JDK1.8.0_111 and when I open it, it displays the screen but does not show the window to begin writing code. 
!C:\Users\Shane\Pictures\Camera Roll\Captue.png
I hope the picture loads but I need help. My homework is due in 5 days and I asked my teacher for help solving this issue and he was useless.

Comment: try removing netbeans completely, reboot your computer and then install it again. if it still doesnt work, update your post with JDK as well. also try running netbeans from command line, so you may see any errors on the console

Comment: Well, you're supposed to create a class or file if you want to write code. Did you do so?

Comment: There is no default window to write code in any of IDE's. The java code can be written even in the notepad in a file with `.java` extension.

Comment: I suggest that you remove the last sentence of your question. It is not helpful and it makes it less likely that you will receive assistance here. Also, your screen shot does not render - you need to fix that as well.

Comment: It looks like Netbeans may be having problems locating the correct version of Java to use. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54278367/2985643) for a possible solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to version difference try jdk 1.7 or try using different IDE like eclipse or Intelij.(I prefer eclipse) or even Netbeans 10.Netbeans have some compatibility issues with jdk1.8