# Can't open certain .java files in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, ide

I am using Netbeans 11.1. I just noticed that if I try to open a past project in Netbeans, sometimes it will open, but other projects won't open. If I go into the src folder through Netbeans, the src folder is empty. But if I go find the file on my hard drive the src file contains the code. However, when I try to open it it just won't open. I don't understand what's going on.

Comment: Whats appears on the Netbeans file log?

Comment: @JoãoZarate I don't know what that means.

Comment: Is there anything written in your Netbeans log file? To find the log file, follow this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50462124/netbeans-where-to-find-the-ide-log

Comment: @JoãoZarate I found the log file. Yes there is something in there from a few minutes ago. But it's a huge text file. What am I looking for in there?

Comment: Clean the log file, replicates the error and paste the log here. Will be easier to help you

Comment: How to clean it and generate a new log file?

Comment: Maybe closing the Netbeans and renaming the file.
You can open this file in another text editor, select all text and delete it, and save it.

Comment: @JoãoZarate I did that, restarted Netbeans, and it generated another huge text file. Now what?

Comment: Ok ... try open the log file in another text editor, clean all content, and save it. After that, replicates the error and paste the log here.... Keep the Netbeans opened

Answer (score 0):

In the projects section where your projects are, right-click on your projects that aren't opening and and select "Convert to J2SE Project'.