# I am opening netbeans and it's loading but screen is not shown on monitor. and when I again open it, it just shows a blank window can any body help me

Tags: java, netbeans, ide, netbeans-7, netbeans-platform

it says in task manager task is not allowed

[image]

Comment: NetBeans is probably throwing an exception during startup. Update your question to show the content of the NetBeans logfile written during the startup. Normally you would access that log file within NetBeans using **View > IDE Log**, but in your case you will probably have to locate the file on disk and then open it in a text editor. See [NetBeans - where to find the IDE log?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50462124/2985643) for details on how to locate that log file.

Comment: Does this file ends with .properties extension.

Comment: No. The NetBeans log file is named `messages.log`, and it resides in the **var/log** directory within your NetBeans installation.