# Apache NetBeans taking to long to load on first run

Tags: netbeans, archlinux

I have just installed Apache NetBeans on my Arch Linux desktop, and on the first run it is taking a very long time to load. Is this a problem with NetBeans? If so, how do i fix it? My computer has 4gb of ram and a 2-core CPU.

Comment: @andrewJames By "load" I mean for the window to change some color other than plain white. I actually have not been able to get into it yet, so I don't know anything about NetBeans itself other than it's running on jre-openjdk 18.0.2 and it says "Apache Netbeans IDE 15" on the window title. I do not know where the log files are located. I installed it as a snap.

Comment: In case it helps: [NetBeans - where to find the IDE log?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50462124/netbeans-where-to-find-the-ide-log)

Answer (score 1):

I have done some research on the Manjaro forum [here](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/netbeans-not-working-java-issue/30539) and found that running `_JAVA_AWT_WM_NONREPARENTING=1 netbeans` in a terminal will make the editor work.