# Apache NetBeans 12.6 not opening on windows 10

Tags: java, netbeans, startup

I'm having an issue with NetBeans, on the first few startups everything works fine, and I even get some projects finished, but then suddenly Netbeans loads but doesn't open, and if I try to reopen it all I get is a minimized menu bar (as if you took the menu bar on the top right of your screen and only displayed that). I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling the application, changing the JDK being used, and failed at editing a config file which I saw suggested on some other threads, this happens independent of the version installed or the JDK used. I'm really lost because I don't even get an error message.

Comment: Which JDKs did you try (have you configured it in <NetBeans-Program Folder>\etc\netbeans.conf?) Have you deleted %USERPROFILE\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\12.1 already? You can also try to delete %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\12.1. BTW: NetBeans 15 was released...

Comment: Did you take a look in the logs?

Comment: @Mihe Second suggestion fixed the issue, genuinely don't know where this problem came from. Also, I understand Netbeans 15 has been released, I reverted to older versions to see If the problem persisted. Nevertheless, I appreciate the help a lot.

Comment: @NicholasC Good that you resolved your issue, but FYI if you get a similar problem again, you need to look in the NetBeans log file for details about that problem. It is a text file and you can view it within NetBeans using **View > IDE Log**. If NetBeans is not running, see [NetBeans - where to find the IDE log?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50462124/2985643) for details on how to locate that file within your file system, though it is usually somewhere under directory `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\` on Windows.