# Netbeans 12.2 does not open on my win 11. I have already installed jdk 19.0.2. Does anyone know what is wrong?

Tags: java, installation, netbeans, reset, windows-11

I have already installed jdk 19.0.2. Then I installed netbeans 12.2 but it does not open after the installation. I reset my pc but it still does not work

I installed java before netbeans but before that I have netbeans installed and I uninstalled it some time ago and now it does not open after reinstallation

Comment: Not all versions of NetBeans work with all versions of Java - for example, see the [download notes](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb122/nb122.html) for NetBeans 12.2, where it states "_Apache NetBeans 12.2 runs on JDK LTS releases 8 and 11, as well as on JDK 15, i.e., the current JDK release at the time of this NetBeans release._".

Comment: Downgrade Java (or install an additional, compatible version) or upgrade NetBeans.

Comment: Now is 2023, Apache NetBeans 17.

Comment: Just to add: It is often helpful to see what the NetBeans log file contains, in these situations. See [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73832367/apache-netbeans-12-6-not-opening-on-windows-10#comment130375101_73832367) for notes on where to find the log file.

Comment: I try to find any error and my case is this error : java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The Security Manager is deprecated and will be removed in a future release
        at java.base/java.lang.System.setSecurityManager(System.java:430)
        at org.netbeans.TopSecurityManager.install(TopSecurityManager.java:525)
        at org.netbeans.core.NbLifecycleManager.advancePolicy(NbLifecycleManager.java:69)
        at org.netbeans.core.GuiRunLevel.run(GuiRunLevel.java:84)
        at org.netbeans.core.startup.Main.start(Main.java:295)
I am surender and install nb20

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a Netbeans on version 12.5 and jdk on version 8 or 11 depending on my project, maybe you can try do a downgrade on your jdk for using on your netbeans. If this process don't work to you, must be necessary reinstall your netbeans and indicates the new jdk on this process, it goes without saying the version of jdk can be changing acording to the dependency of your project ;).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).