# Issues NetBeans - I can´t open NetBeans-16

Tags: netbeans-16

The Folder NetBeans isn´t in the path AppData/Roaming.

I already uninstalled and installed it several times and it didn´t work.

Thank you!!!

Comment: A common cause of this issue is that NetBeans can't find Java, or is finding an invalid/unsupported version of Java, when it starts. But regardless of the cause, diagnostic information will have been written to the NetBeans log, so update your question with the relevant portion of that log. The name of the log file is **messages.log**. See [NetBeans - where to find the IDE log?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50462124/netbeans-where-to-find-the-ide-log) for details on locating that file.

Comment: While you have edited your question, you have not updated it to show the content of the NetBeans log file as mentioned in my previous comment. Without that information I don't think your issue can be resolved because the diagnostics for any problem that occurs when starting NetBeans are in that file. As a separate matter, [NetBeans 17 was released recently](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/index.html), so you might consider installing that to see if it works for you. There's is no need to uninstall NetBeans 16 first, because both versions can coexist without any problem.

Comment: I'll install NetBeans 17 and I hope it resolves the matter, Thank You so much.

Comment: It worked, I installed NetBeans 17 and it worked. Thanks.