Netbeans crash in turning on module automatically
I have installed netbeans 21 and jdk21. But when i tried to launch, netbeans couldn't pass through "turning on modules", and then automatically crashed without any message dialog. I tried some solution but none of them worked. Please help me. Thankyou!

Have you checked the log file? (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50462124/netbeans-where-to-find-the-ide-log)
